# Contacts.app - list all groups a contact is in

Tags: contacts, contacts.app

Is there a possibility to list all the groups, a contact is in, on the card.
This would make the organisation of my contacts much easier

Comment: You can hold down the "Option" key to highlight the groups the selected contact is in, if the "Groups" pane is open.

Comment: You're welcome.  :)  (Guess I'll add that as an answer.)  You might also be interested in [my related question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254601/151730) as to how this highlighting can be turned on permanently.  I know it's possible because I've done it accidentally, but I don't know how.  (Hopefully I'll get an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution doesn't list the groups *on the contact card* itself, but it may still solve your situation:

By holding down the "Option" key when you have a contact selected and the "Groups" pane showing, the groups which contain the selected contact are highlighted.

Related:

- [Highlight the groups a contact is in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254601/151730)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskDifferent!

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is no.  The default Contacts app does not allow you to do this.  I believe there's some third-party apps that will do this but you'll have to search the App Store to find one.